# Is it possible to run Linux utils from Mathematica using Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: windows, interoperability, linux, external-calls

I have Windows 10 Professional x64 with WSL2 installed. I've also installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from Microsoft Store.

I can type `ubuntu2004` in the CMD and get access to Linux utils installed under Ubuntu. For example, I've [installed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41261835/590388) the `poppler-utils` and now have `pdfunite`:

[image: screenshot]

My disk `C:\` is already mounted in the Ubuntu filesystem as `/mnt/c` and I have full access to it from my Ubuntu:

[image: screenshot2]

Suppose I have copied (under Windows) two PDF files into this directory, say `1.pdf` and `2.pdf`:

[image: screenshot3]

And I wish to combine them using `pdfunite` from Ubuntu, but I want to perform this programmatically from *Mathematica*, without using the terminal interface. Under the terminal, it would be sufficient just to type:

```
pdfunite 1.pdf 2.pdf combined.pdf
```

But how can I do this from *Mathematica* using perhaps such commands as `RunProcess` or `ExternalEvaluate`?

P.S. `pdfunite` is just an example. Actually I wish to understand how I can use any Ubuntu command-line utility from *Mathematica* installed on Windows.

Comment: One option I've heard works quite well is to just use the linux version of Mathematica *instead* of the Windows version, but I have no first-hand experience with that. If that is too drastic, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49186380/4712538) will help?

Comment: If that link is relevant I would try `RunProcess[{"wsl", "pdfunite", "1.pdf", "2.pdf", "combined.pdf"}]`, assuming the PDFs are on the path and all.

Comment: @JasonB. Thank you, I've found that in the Windows terminal `ubuntu2004 run pdfunite 1.pdf 2.pdf combined.pdf` works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49186380/4712538) linked by [Jason B.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9490/jason-b), after experimenting a bit I've found that it is as easy as follows:

```
SetDirectory["C:\\Mathematica_work"];
RunProcess[{"ubuntu2004", "run", "pdfunite", "1.pdf", "2.pdf", "combined.pdf"}]
```

> ```
> <|"ExitCode" -> 0, "StandardOutput" -> "", "StandardError" -> ""|>
> ```

Now we got the desired `combined.pdf`:

```
FileNames[]
```

> ```
> {"1.pdf", "2.pdf", "combined.pdf"}
> ```